# A simple query in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Need to make a stored procedure that will do a simple search on a table, plus have 3 parameters, the first two are a date range, the third is if different from NULL will be included in the WHERE, if equal to NULL then not seek that value, as I can do this search?

Comment: `WHERE @parameter1 = ColA AND @parameter2 = ColB AND (@parameter3 IS NULL OR @parameter3 = ColC)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Where @parameter1 = ColA 
AND @parameter2 = ColB 
and ISNULL(@parameter3, ColC) = ColC
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..
`Create Prucedure test`

`@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 nvarchar(50)`

```
As

Begin
```

`If @p3 is null`

`Select * from table where field1=@p1 and field2=@p2`

```
Else
Select * from table where field1=@p1 and field2=@p2 and field3=@p3
End
```

Sorry for improper formatting this is because i am sending the answer from a cell phone

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE @parameter IS NULL or field = @parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can do that by passing the three variables to the host program and write a customized `CURSOR SELECT` using them. Then `open the cursor` and `throw the resultset`. Your search results are now ready to use. If needed syntactical help, revert with the host language and specifications you are using. Do post the challenges and solution you got for the same, may help others.

Comment: What? No, that answer doesn't even make sense given the context of the tags (SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Note that if Column3 could be null then you need to use the isnull() function on the column name as well as you can't compare null values. So if the data type of Column3 is int then you could use: and isnull(Column3, 0) = isnull(@param3, isnull(Column3, 0)).

```
create procedure Test
    @param1 varchar(50),
    @param2 varchar(50),
    @param3 varchar(50) = null
as
begin
    select *
    from Table1
    where Column1 = @param1
    and Column2 = @param2
    and Column3 = isnull(@param3, Column3)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The general form of what you are attempting to perform is a dynamic query. See the solution in this problem [update statement not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621364/update-statement-not-executing/7621439#7621439)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the adventure works database.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE upContactDetails
        @FirstName  [nvarchar](50),
        @LastName   [nvarchar](50),
        @MiddleName [nvarchar](50)
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT     Title
             , FirstName
             , MiddleName
             , LastName
             , EmailAddress
    FROM       Person.Contact
    WHERE (@MiddleName IS NULL or MiddleName = @MiddleName) 
          AND FirstName = @FirstName
          AND LastName  = @LastName 
    END
    GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that You're having a transaction table where you store transaction Number And Transaction Date as shown Below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TrnMast](
    [TrnNo] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
    [AcYear] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Comp_Code] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [InvNo] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [TrnDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [P_Code] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Amount] [money] NULL,
    [Remark] [varchar](50) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TrnMast_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TrnNo] ASC,
    [Comp_Code] ASC,
    [AcYear] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Now Look at stored procedure with 3 parameters having two date range paramaters and TrnNo Below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_TrnMast] 
    @FTrnDate SmallDateTime = Null,
    @TTrnDate SmallDateTime = Null,
    @AcYear Int
AS
Begin   
        Select * From TrnMast           
        Where (@FTrnDate Is Null Or TrnMast.TrnDate >= @FTrnDate) 
          And (@TTrnDate Is Null Or TrnMast.TrnDate <= @TTrnDate) 
          And TrnMast.AcYear = @AcYear 

End
```